# Trouble calling multiple plotting functions from one python file

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot

I have several files that I am currently turning into functions. Each function makes a plot from a csv file and works successfully on its own. I am now trying to combine them all into the one code that will call each function and create the plots all at once. The issue that I'm having is that I am calling the functions correctly except only one plot will open. The second (and subsequent) don't open until the previous one is closed. My code is:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import os.path 
from Ux import Ux_plotting
from prgh import prgh_plotting

print "Creating post-processing plots..."

if os.path.exists("Ux.py") and os.path.exists("Uz.py") and os.path.exists("prgh.py") and os.path.exists("forces.py") and os.path.exists("magvorticity.py"):
   print "All good. Next step..."
else:
   print "Uh oh. Better make sure you have all of your files."

Ux_plotting()
prgh_plotting()
```

Anybody have some advice on this?

I'm trying to write my first python codes so please be patient :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have `plt.show()` at the end of your `Ux_plotting` and `prgh_plotting` functions. `plt.show()` is a blocking function: i.e. it will show any figures, and stop anything else happening until the figure window is closed.

I think you have (at least) two options;

1) move the `plt.show()` into your main script, after your two plotting calls, since ([from the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show)), `show()` will show all figures created:

> matplotlib.pyplot.show(*args, **kw)
>
> Display a figure.
>
> In non-interactive mode, **display all figures and block until the figures have been closed**

2) Alternatively, you could try setting `block=False` in the first plotting function's `show`: `plt.show(block=False)`, which should allow the code to continue until the next `plt.show()` in the second plotting function.

Comment: Ahh that explains it... I suspected it was plot.show() so I commented that line out and it did successfully save everything and do what I wanted.Thanks for your explanation though, I just did trial and error and it worked but wasn't too sure why